# Do class members need to be prefixed with `class::` in class definitions?

Tags: c++, class, namespaces

When defining a class `cls`, is it necessary (or good practice) to prefix the class name `cls::` to members when using them within `cls`'s own definition, or is it done implicitly? E.g.

```
class cls {
    int x;
    void foo();
    void bar();
}
void cls::foo() {
    x++;    // or use cls::x?
    bar();  // or cls::bar()?
}
```

If so, then does creating a class `cls` automatically mean that it is also a namespace (since I thought `::` operator was only used with namespaces)?

*Edit (follow up):*
If we don't use `cls::` or `this->`, then what if my source also has a variable `x` outside the class? How will `cls::foo()` know which one `x++` refers to?

Comment: It is moderately common to prefix the names of member variables such as 'x', often with 'm_' (ie 'm_x').  This helps to distinguish local variables from class members, thereby removing one reason why you might want to scope your members with the class-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you show above *defines* a class, but initially only *declares* the member functions (and then *defines* them just afterwards). I only mention this because the terminology is important for effective communication.

If you define the class members inline then you don't use the *scope resolution operator* `::`, for example:

```
class cls {
    void hello() { cout << "Hello world"; }
};
```

If you define them separately then you *do* need it, because otherwise the compiler cannot know what function exactly you intend to define:

```
class cls {
    void hello();
};

void cls::hello() { cout << "Hello world"; };
```

In general, usage of the scope resolution operator is not restricted to working with namespaces; you use it whenever there is need to provide a *fully qualified name* to the compiler.

When accessing class members from inside the class scope in most cases you can use their unqualified names; the compiler will resolve them on its own. So for example, in your code all of these are equivalent:

```
x++;
cls::x++;
this->x++;
this->cls::x++; // yes, this too
```

You need to qualify the names whenever there are multiple members with the same name and the compiler resolves an unqualified name to something other than the member you intended. Examples:

```
void cls::foo(int x) {
    x++;       // increments the argument
    cls::x++;  // increments the member
    this->x++; // also increments the member
}
```

Consider also that `cls` may derive from `base`, and `base` may also define a `x`. In that case it works like this:

```
void cls::foo() {
    x++;       // increments foo::x
    cls::x++;  // increments foo::x
    base::x++; // increments base::x
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea to explicitly qualify member variable use with the class name. At best, it's unnecessary (or where it's necessary, this->member is better) and inhibits refactoring (more places to change if you rename the class), at worst it introduces bugs because qualified calls to virtual functions do not dispatch to overridden versions.

Answer (score 1):

Nop. At least not with that.

You can use `this->` to make it clearer for the reader. However `::` is a different thing. It is used to access static member variables or function.

```
int x;                  // Global x
namespace ot { int x; } // another x
class cls {
    int x;              // Normal member
    static int y;       // Static member
    void foo();
    static void bar();  // Static member function
}
void cls::foo() {
    this->x++;    // Modify own x. 
    x++           // Modify own x. This has implicit this->
    ::x++;        // Modify the global x.
    ot::x++;      // Modify the x in namespace ot.
    cls::y++;     // modify the static member
    cls::bar();   // static member function. same as bar()
}
```

Comment: So what if my source also has a variable `x` outside the class? How will cls::foo() know which one `x++` refers to if we don't use `this`?

Comment: `::` _can_ be used with non-static data and function members and can be used to disable virtual dispatch.

Comment: Is it the same for nested classes?

Comment: @MiloChen if you want to access a **static** member of a nested class `Nest` then  you do it like `Nest::x++`. if you want to access a **NON static** member of a nested class then you need an **object** of that class e.g `Nested nt; nt.x++`

Comment: And finally, what about from one nested class to another? i.e. if `cls` has 2 child classes at the same level.

Comment: @MiloChen Same thing The basic rule is if the class can be reached from where you are you jut write `cls::`. so for two nested classes in **the same level** i.e. `cls::nested1` and `cls::nested2`, if you are in `nested2` you do `nested1::x`. But remember this is only for **static** members. for other memebers you need an object to use.